# My button for guess is greyed out, but there are no errors why is that?

Tags: java

[Greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2j2w.png)

Hi, I'm taking a beginners Programming 11 course in high school and our teacher does not teach at all.

We are doing JavaFX and I smh managed to get the program to run but the program doesn't let me submit my guess. When I looked at the code I needed to it seemed correct so I don't get the issue.

There are no code errors, so it may be a Logical error

Here is the code below, if you need more info I can help.

Controller Class (snippet (where I think the error is)

```
public void rollDice() {
        // Roll the dice and update the roll label
        currentRoll = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        rollLabel.setText("You rolled a " + currentRoll);

        // Disable the Roll button and enable the guess text field
        rollButton.setDisable(true);
        guessTextField.setDisable(false);
    }
```

Controller Class (full)

```
package com.example.dicegamechance;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.util.Random;

public class HelloController {

    @FXML
    private Label rollLabel; // Reference to the label that displays the current roll

    @FXML
    private Label resultLabel; // Reference to the label that displays the result of the guess

    @FXML
    private TextField guessTextField; // Reference to the text field where the user enters their guess

    @FXML
    private Button rollButton; // Reference to the button that rolls the dice

    private Random random = new Random(); // Random number generator for rolling the dice

    private int currentRoll; // The value of the current roll
    private int currentScore; // The user's current score

    // Method called when the Roll button is clicked
    public void rollDice() {
        // Roll the dice and update the roll label
        currentRoll = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        rollLabel.setText("You rolled a " + currentRoll);

        // Disable the Roll button and enable the guess text field
        rollButton.setDisable(true);
        guessTextField.setDisable(false);
    }

    // Method called when the Guess button is clicked
    public void checkGuess() {
        // Generate the next roll and get the user's guess
        int nextRoll = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        String guess = guessTextField.getText();

        // Clear the guess text field and disable it
        guessTextField.setText("");
        guessTextField.setDisable(true);

        // Re-enable the Roll button
        rollButton.setDisable(false);

        // Check if the user guessed correctly and update the result label
        if (guess.equals("h") && nextRoll > currentRoll) {
            resultLabel.setText("You guessed correctly! Your score is now " + (++currentScore));
        } else if (guess.equals("l") && nextRoll < currentRoll) {
            resultLabel.setText("You guessed correctly! Your score is now " + (++currentScore));
        } else {
            resultLabel.setText("You guessed incorrectly. Your score remains at " + currentScore);
        }
    }
```

I tried to work on changing some values from true and false and checked over my code by reading through it a few times.

I want the player to roll a die then guess if the next is higher or lower, after that they roll again to see if they win or lose.